# Laravel 4.2 Query Builder Not working Perfectly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

My DB is like this
[image: Database]

I have a Laravel 4.2 Query Builder Code

```
           DB::table(DB::raw('`car` , `available_car`, `users`'))
                ->select('car.car_maker', 'car.car_model', 'available_car.car_price', 'car.car_production_year', 'available_car.car_id', 'available_car.id', 'available_car.current_position')
                //Where
                    //Basic Parts
                    ->where('available_car.car_id', '=' , '`car`.`car_id`')
                    ->where('available_car.is_sold', '=', 'no')
                    ->whereRaw('`available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
                //Ordering
                ->orderByRaw('WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC')
                ->orderBy('available_car.car_price', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('users.last_paid_date', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('available_car.created_at', 'desc')
                ->distinct();
        echo $query->count();
        $info = $query->get();
```

Here if I want to know what query is executed I have used this code

```
$info = $query->get();
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

Now I get This output

```
0{"query":"select distinct `car`.`car_maker`, `car`.`car_model`, `available_car`.`car_price`, `car`.`car_production_year`, `available_car`.`car_id`, `available_car`.`id`, `available_car`.`current_position` from `car` , `available_car`, `users` where `available_car`.`car_id` = ? and `available_car`.`is_sold` = ? and `available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() order by WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC, `available_car`.`car_price` desc, `users`.`last_paid_date` desc, `available_car`.`created_at` desc","bindings":["`car`.`car_id`","no"],"time":1.03}
```

If I run this output code in PHP MyAdmin Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `car`.`car_maker` ,  `car`.`car_model` ,  `available_car`.`car_price` ,  `car`.`car_production_year` ,  `available_car`.`car_id` ,  `available_car`.`id` ,  `available_car`.`current_position` 
FROM  `car` ,  `available_car` ,  `users` 
WHERE  `available_car`.`car_id` =  `car`.`car_id` 
AND  `available_car`.`is_sold` =  'no'
AND  `available_car`.`created_at` 
BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 
DAY AND NOW( ) 
ORDER BY WEEK(  `available_car`.`created_at` ) DESC ,  `available_car`.`car_price` DESC ,  `users`.`last_paid_date` DESC , `available_car`.`created_at` DESC
```

I have Output like this

[image: SQL Output]

So, I get empty row in Laravel and get 8 row in raw query for the same SQL query.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: From your example I don't see you assigning the build query to the variable like so `$query = DB::table(...`. Are you doing that within your actual code and it is just something you forgot to put in the question example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binding.

Or you can use Joining.

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you **can not bind table and column names**

that's why your query is failing (*more accurately, not giving the desired result*).

```
"bindings":["`car`.`car_id`","no"]
```

here you are binding *car.car_id*

it won't work. following should work.

```
->whereRaw('`available_car`.`car_id` =`car`.`car_id`')
```

this should give the same result as phpmyadmin.